# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python

esto es una parte del programa original, soy nuevo en Python y hay algunas cosas que aun no entiendo.

```
def Riemann(a, b, n, l, f):
    numRange = np.arange(a,b, .02)
    y = f(numRange)
    w = float(b - a)/n
    x = 0.0
    d = {"l": 0, "r": 1, "m": 0.5}
    offset = d[l[0]]
    for i in range(n):
        x += f(a + (i+offset)*w)
        plt.gca().add_patch(matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((i*w + a,0),w,f(a + (i+offset)*w)))
    plt.plot(numRange, y, color=(1.0, 0.00, 0.00), zorder=5)
    s = w * x
    print ('\n', s, '\n')
```

Comment: ¿En cual línea te da el error? ¿Chequeaste el tipo y contenido de las variables involucradas (hint: usa `print`)? ¿Con que valores llamas a la función? Por favor, incluye la llamada que estas haciendo.

Comment: No creo que el error esté en el código que muestras. La única línea en ese código que intenta una división es `w = float(b-a)/n` pero esa línea no puede producir el error que muestras, pues a la izquierda del `/` no tenemos una cadena (el resultado de `float()` no puede ser una cadena). Revisa el mensaje de error que Python muestra pues en él debe aparecer la línea que está causando el problema. Actualiza la pregunta con la información relevante.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'